# How can I use odoo's server side onchange method, inside a create function?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

For example, if I want to trigger this function:

```
@api.onchange("fieldA")
def _onchange(self):
   for rec in self:
        random = rec.fieldB
```

The onchange function is commonly of the form: `onchange(values, field_name, field_onchange)`

**Sub-question 1:** I require fieldB to be available already. Do I pass it into the "values" argument? 
**Sub-question 2:** Could the answerer provide a proper code example?

---

The common example given in the references is usually with the form:

```
wizard = self.env['library.return.wizard']
values = {'borrower_id': self.env.user.partner_id.id}
specs = wizard._onchange_spec()
updates = wizard.onchange(values, ['borrower_id'], specs)
....
....
wiz = wizard.create(values)
```

But this **does not work** in my case..

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out. There are some hidden gotchas:

1. self.onchange actually calls both @api.depends, and @api.onchange decorated functions
2. values dict (1st arg of self.onchange) actually serves 2 uses: check my code below
3. (observation) self.onchange returned value dict, does not include fields that were **not** modified by the functions called via self.onchange

You may refer to my code comments below for more details.
Hope this helps someone.

```py
 @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        # SECTION: Trigger server-side onchange to initialize all child dependent values of qty_to_ship. More generally, to trigger all @api.onchange functions in this shipment.item model.
        
        stock_move = self.env['stock.move'].browse([vals['move_id']])
        # 'values' dict: (1) provide values of fields when used in calling onchange functions (2) indicate fields that we want a return value for after calling onchange
        # Note: some key-values are commented because related fields of move_id will be computed when we call self.onchange
        values = {
            # 'product_id': stock_move.product_id.id,
            # 'product_tmpl_id': stock_move.product_id.product_tmpl_id.id,
            'move_id': stock_move.id,
            'qty_to_ship': stock_move.product_uom_qty,
            'carton_qty': 0,
            'item_sub_total': 0,
        }
        specs = self._onchange_spec()
        # Note: self.onchange, triggers both @api.depends, @api.onchange decorated functions (this is not mentioned in any documentation)
        # Note: the order of the list (2nd arg) matters
        # move_id needed to: trigger def _assign_relational_fields
        # product_tmpl_id needed to: trigger def _compute_carton_single
        # qty_to_ship needed to: trigger other functions with @api.onchange('qty_to_ship') decorator
        updates = self.onchange(values, ['move_id', 'product_tmpl_id', 'qty_to_ship'], specs)
        value = updates.get('value', {}) 
        for name, val in value.items(): 
            if isinstance(val, tuple): 
                value[name] = val[0]
        vals.update(value)
        # insert qty_to_ship as it is not modified by any of the onchange functions triggered earlier. Hence it will not be attached to 'value' dict
        vals.update({'qty_to_ship': stock_move.product_uom_qty})

        # Continue with super create
        res = super(ACDShipmentItems, self).create(vals)

        return res
```